# Obtain the MLE of $\theta$

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_n$ constitute a random sample from a uniform distribution with probability function:
$$
f(y|\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta + 1}, 0 \le y \le 2\theta + 1
$$

Obtain the MLE of $\theta$.

I found that the likelihood function is
$$
\bigg(\frac{1}{2\theta + 1}\bigg) ^n
$$
on the interval $[0, 2\theta + 1]$.

The likelihood is increasing as $\theta$ decreases. The smallest value that can maximize the likelihood is max$(Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n) = Y_{(n)} = 2\theta + 1$.

From this, I thought that the MLE should be $\hat{\theta} = Y_{(n)} = 2\theta + 1$, but the solution key says that is should be $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{2}(Y_{(n)} - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to write problems like this using the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) 
$$L(\theta | \mathbf{Y}) = \left( \frac{1}{2\theta + 1} \right)^n\mathbf{1}_{[0,2\theta+1]}(Y_1)...\mathbf{1}_{[0,2\theta+1]}(Y_n)  $$

$$ =\left( \frac{1}{2\theta + 1} \right)^n\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty]}(Y_{(1)})\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,2\theta +1]}(Y_{(n)}) $$

The likelihood function decreases with $\theta$ over its support

$$\{\theta : Y_{(n)} \leq 2\theta +1\}  $$

To maximize the likelihood, choose the minimum $\theta$ value within the support

$$
Y_{(n)} =2\hat{\theta}+1  $$

$$
\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}(Y_{(n)}-1)  $$

Answer (score 0):

The solution key says that it is $\frac{1}{2}(Y_{(n)} - 1)$ because $Y_{(n)}$ is an estimator, but it is bias. To correct the bias, it has to equal $\theta$. So that is the subtracting 1 from $Y_{(n)}$ and multipltying that by 2; this gives $\frac{1}{2}(Y_{(n)} - 1)$.

Comment: It is not required that the MLE is unbiased. In fact, the MLE for this problem is a biased estimator (It would be easy to prove that $E(\frac{1}{2}(Y_{(n)}-1)) < \theta $ for finite $n$).